# How to perform Complex SQL join with multiple approximate matches and return only the first match

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to perform a Left join in SQL where I need to **check multiple match criteria** and only retain the **first match** in the right table after a certain **sort operation on the right table.**

Below is my Left table.
(No Null values)

| Date | Customer | Shop | Product | Customer_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | C1 | S1 | P1 | 2 |
| 1/2/2020 | C2 | S1 | P2 | 8 |
| 1/5/2020 | C3 | S2 | P1 | 6 |
| 1/6/2020 | C4 | S2 | P2 | 10 |
| 1/7/2020 | C1 | S2 | P3 | 2 |
| 1/8/2020 | C2 | S2 | P4 | 4 |

And this is the right Table
(Null values allowed only in Product column)

| Shop | Product | Min_Customer_Score | Valid_From | Valid_To | Percent_Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | P1 | 4 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 10 |
| S1 | P1 | 5 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 11 |
| S1 | P1 | 7 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 12 |
| S1 |  | 5 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 13 |
| S2 | P1 | 4 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 14 |
| S2 | P2 | 4 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 15 |
| S2 |  | 6 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 16 |
| S2 |  | 9 | 1/1/2020 | 1/5/2020 | 17 |
| S2 | P1 | 4 | 1/6/2020 | 1/8/2020 | 18 |
| S2 | P2 | 4 | 1/6/2020 | 1/8/2020 | 19 |
| S2 |  | 6 | 1/6/2020 | 1/8/2020 | 20 |
| S2 |  | 9 | 1/6/2020 | 1/8/2020 | 21 |

I want to sort the right table **first by Product(nulls at last) and then by Min_Customer_Score(ascending).**
Then I want to pull the Min_Customer_Score and Discount value from first row matching below conditions:

1. Left.Date >= Right.Valid_From
2. Left.Date <= Right.Valid_To
3. Left.Shop = Right.Shop
4. Left.Product = Right.Product **OR** Right.Product = null
5. Left.Customer_Score >= Right.Min_Customer_Score

My final result should look like below.

| Date | Customer | Shop | Product | Customer_Score | Min_Customer_Score | Percent_Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | C1 | S1 | P1 | 2 | null | null |
| 1/2/2020 | C2 | S1 | P2 | 8 | 5 | 13 |
| 1/5/2020 | C3 | S2 | P1 | 6 | 4 | 14 |
| 1/6/2020 | C4 | S2 | P2 | 10 | 4 | 19 |
| 1/7/2020 | C1 | S2 | P3 | 2 | null | null |
| 1/8/2020 | C2 | S2 | P4 | 4 | null | null |

Basically, I want to find the right discount for each purchase, considering **null values in the Right.Product as default discount** that is applicable to all other products.

I am familiar with making Left Joins and also using Sub Queries in SQL. But I couldn't even understand where to start to do such complex queries. I have also referred to other answers which suggest using `ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY`, But couldn't work it out for this case.

**Edit:**
This is what I was able to work out so far.

```
SELECT left_table.*, right_table.Percent_Discount, right_table.Min_Customer_Score
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY left_table.Date, left_table.Customer, left_table.Shop, left_table.Product 
  ORDER BY right_table.Product DESC right_table.Min_Customer_Score ASC) as row_num
LEFT JOIN right_table
  ON left_table.Date >= right_table.Valid_From
  AND left_table.Date <= right_table.Valid_To
  AND left_table.Shop>= right_table.Shop
  AND (left_table.Product = right_table.Product OR right_table.Product is NULL)
  AND left_table.Customer_Score >= right_table.Min_Customer_Score
WHERE row_num = 1
```

But It gives me below error

```
ERROR:  column "row_num" does not exist
LINE: WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: Using `row_number` is the right approach here.  Do the `left join` as you have outlined in your question, include the `row_number` in that `select` and then filter for those where the `row_number = 1`.  Your `partition by` is the group of values you want to only return one row from and the `order by` determines the order of rows within that `partition`.  Try to write this script and add what you have tried into this question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks @iamdave, I tried as you suggested and added that code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve it as below. Thanks to @iamdave for your comment

```
SELECT Date, Customer, Shop, Product, Customer_Score, Min_Customer_Score, Percent_Discount
FROM
(
    SELECT left_table.*, right_table.Percent_Discount, right_table.Min_Customer_Score
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY left_table.Date, left_table.Customer, left_table.Shop, left_table.Product 
      ORDER BY right_table.Product DESC right_table.Min_Customer_Score ASC) as row_num
    LEFT JOIN right_table
      ON left_table.Date >= right_table.Valid_From
      AND left_table.Date <= right_table.Valid_To
      AND left_table.Shop = right_table.Shop
      AND (left_table.Product = right_table.Product OR right_table.Product is NULL)
      AND left_table.Customer_Score >= right_table.Min_Customer_Score
) as sub_query
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply`:

```
select l.*, r.*
from left l outer apply
     (select top (1)
      from right r
      where l.Date >= r.Valid_From and
            l.Date <= r.Valid_To and
            l.Shop = r.Shop and
            (l.Product = r.Product or r.Product = null) and
            (l.Customer_Score >= r.Min_Customer_Score)
      order by (case when product is not null then 1 else 2 end),
               Min_Customer_Score asc
     ) r
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach works. I am a little worried about the performance though as my left table is big. Will this make separate database queries for each row in the left table?

Comment: @ArjunAriyil *"I am a little worried about the performance though"* - Have you tested both queries on your data to compare?  If not, do so and use whichever performs best.

Comment: @ArjunAriyil . . . You have to go through all the rows of the left table.  The right table probably has a bigger impact on performance.